# dynamic select for menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to select a SuperCategory which then filters the drop down for MainCategories. I am getting the following error

undefined method `map' for :main_categories:Symbol

with the code

```
<%= select_tag 'main_category_id', grouped_collection_select(:main_category_id, SuperCategory.active.order(:title), :main_categories, :title, :id, :title, include_blank: false) %>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to have two selects? Where the values in the second select are contingent upon what was selected in the first select?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change second and third parameters.
Because: 
2 parameter - method - The attribute of object corresponding to the select tag
3 parameter - collection - An array of objects representing the  tags.

In your code third parameter is Symbol and it's doesn't have method "map".

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Comment: you are correct.  I had to add an addition attribute

Answer (score 0):

this ended up working for

```
<%= grouped_collection_select('grouped', :main_category_ids, SuperCategory.exclude_most_popular, 'sort_main_categories', :title, :id, :title, {  :selected => selected_main, include_blank: false } ) %>
```